# Unable to start service SQLSERVERAGENT on server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I moved my Data and log files and I tired to start the SQL Server. But it says:

> Unable to Start Service on Server X. (mscorlib)
>
> The MSSQLSERVER service on PSFACAMDWHSQL2 started and then stopped. (ObjectExplorer).

The SQL Error log:

> Unable to start service MSSQLSERVER on server PSFACAMDWHSQL2. (mscorlib)
>
> Program Location:
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ServiceActionHandler.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ServiceControlProgress.ActionCompletedHandler(IAsyncResult result)
>
> The MSSQLSERVER service on PSFACAMDWHSQL2 started and then stopped. (ObjectExplorer)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which database did you move (system databases or user only), and how? Did you alter database before phisically moving the files?

Comment: Your title talks about Agent, yet the body of your question seems to be dealing with the SQL Server service itself.

Comment: @Dean. I moved the TempDB, Model and MSDB and a user Data base. I haven't moved Master as I was leaving it last.

Comment: I just noticed Service Account name in Sql server Configuration Manager is not right but if so will this cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance won't start because `model` database is not where it's expected to be. As a quick fix move the model database's files to their original location and start the instance.

Pls read about moving databases [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189133.aspx).

Comment: Dean: I can't run any queries on SQL because I get this error: 1)A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: What happens, after you copy back the model.mdf and modellog.ldf to original locations, when you try to start the service from SQL Server configuration manager or services applet? If it doesn't start, check the windows error log for error message.

Comment: I checked Windows error log and it confirms what you said it can't find the any of the system database and it mentions: 1) SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution but it works!
Copy the SQL agent user "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" and added it to the local machine(server)'s administrator group (users and group). Once you have done that start your SQL Agent from the SQL Server XXX Configuration Manager. Do the same on SSMS.
I hope that would help.
Thanks